# Raycast from Camera in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to shoot a raycast from the center of the Camera not from mouse position, how can improve my code for this?

```cs
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, rango))
    {
        if (hit.transform.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("ishitting");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```cs
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Placing the center of the input parameter in `ScreenPoint` to Position is not an optimized code and goes through several steps of long calculations. It is better to use the pure **Forward**.

```cs
var main = Camera.main.transform;
Physics.Raycast(main.position, main.forward, 100f);
```